# Sencha Touch 2: How to get (multiple) instances of a base class

Tags: javascript, inheritance, sencha-touch-2

I got the following classes on a Sencha Web App:

**Baseclass**

and **AClass** extends *Baseclass* with xtype aclass

and **BClass** extends *Baseclass* with xtype bclass

Usually I usually would use *Ext.Viewport.down('aclass')* to get a certain instance of a class. My question is if there's a way to get all instances of the Baseclass?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.define('BaseClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    xtype: 'baseclass'
});

Ext.define('AClass', {
    extend: 'BaseClass',
    xtype: 'aclass'
});

Ext.define('BClass', {
    extend: 'BaseClass',
    xtype: 'bclass'
});

var instances = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('baseclass')
```

will return array with all instances of AClass and BClass

Comment: Thanks! Ext.ComponentQuery.query('baseclass') was exactly what I was looking for